# Robot Framework 'Output.xml' copy to different folder

Tags: robotframework

When I am trying to copy the file 'Output.xml' from parent folder to target folder, it is not being copied properly i.e: the file size, in the target folder, is different. I am executing the keyword to copy files in my 'Suite Teardown'. Any solution for the issue.

**Code written to copy files:**

```
OperatingSystem.Copy Files  ${sProjectPath}//output.xml  ${sFinalFolder}
```

Comment: can you paste the code written so far

Comment: added the code @pankaj. The same is happening for 'log.html' also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that while the test is running, the output file doesn't exist. It can't exist during suite teardown, because the result of the suite teardown must be part of the log.

If you need the log in another folder, the simplest solution is to tell robot to write it there initially, with the command line option [--output](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-file) or [--outputdir](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-directory).

If you cannot use `--output`, perhaps the simple solution is to create a script that runs your tests, and then copies the file after it runs. This is mentioned in the user guide in the section titled [Creating start-up scripts](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-start-up-scripts).

A slightly more complex solution is to use a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) which copies the file in the `done` method.

Comment: Yes, I used "--outputdir" option, which generated the reports in my desired directory from the beginning itself.

Answer (score 0):

Robot run reports are created at the end by robot-framework tool. Hence complete result/report files doesn't exist even in suite teardown.

Best practice would be providing --ouput argument with desired output dir.
More detail you can find from  user guide 
[Robot framework user Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-directory) under section 3.5.1

Note:
The command line option --output (-o) determines the path where the output file is created relative to the output directory. The default name for the output file, when tests are run, is output.xml.

Alternative way is use to **rebot** command and act on the output file generated by robot run.
When post-processing outputs with Rebot, new output files are not created unless the --output option is explicitly used.

Answer (score -2):

Whether or not it can be done from Robot Framework script, the question is it should be done from Robot Script. These files could be locked and or changed by the current Robot Framework process. If not today, this could well be a part of any future change in this area.

With this perspective I can only recommend to copy these files prior to the start of Robot Framework, and not after. This ensures that the contents of these files are not changed and are fit for the purpose you have in mind.

As these types of actions are typically not part of a Test Case scenario I consider them to be part of the overarching Orchestration. This includes fetching the right version of the test script from version control software, starting Robot Framework, communicating results (ex. email) and safeguarding the test evidence (Log files and other files).

In general these are standard step functionality in a CI tool like Jenkins, Travis CI or Bamboo (to name a few). Even if you have only started on this path, separating this kind of logic from your test script will save you a lot of effort later on.

Comment: It is impossible to copy the output.xml file prior to the start of Robot Framework, because it doesn't exist prior to the start. This question is specifically about the output.xml file which is generated after the test finishes running.

Comment: When in development, and less experienced teams in production, it happens that the output.xml generated in previous run is overwritten. To prevent this some may want to include this functionality inside their scripts, where this does not belong and suggest to think about CI.

Answer (score -2):

looks like that **Copy Files Kw** does not copy the content of output.xml during Teardown ,although it creates file with samename. As A.Kootstra suggested it could be a limitation currently.

**Alternative:**
in a separate robot script you can rename the file 'output.xml' generated from first script and then can run below command

Copy Files

```
${sProjectPath}//output.xml  ${sFinalFolder}
```

This copies the whole content

Comment: One of the suggestion which I got is posted here [robotframework-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/i8F0MbUXZh0)

Comment: it does not have any solution into it.

Comment: the problem isn't with the `copy files` keyword. The problem is that the output.xml file doesn't exist at the time that the keyword is called.

Comment: ... or if it exists - previous suites in the run have finished, it is not complete and correct xml yet. The last thing to phisically write (phisically, as by definition xml doesnt't have ordering of same level nodes) is the overall *run's* statistics - and this info is not present up until the very last test case is finished.